# Button that will move up/down when the upper line is created/deleted and the button will create a new line with CreationDate, Done and Todo

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need a button that will move up/down when the upper line with "CreationDate, Done, Todo" will be deleted or added. And this button should create line above itself with CreationDate, Done and Todo (I have not this button)

I have the other code, but I think its unnecessary to add here

This is xaml

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgTodoList" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = CreationDate}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="CreationDate" Width="160"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path = IsDone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Done" Width="75"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = Text}" IsReadOnly="False" Header="Todo" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

This is xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly string PATH = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\todoDataList.json";
    private BindingList<TodoModel> _todoDataList;
    private FileIOService _fileIOService;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Message", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _fileIOService = new FileIOService(PATH);

    try
    {
        _todoDataList = _fileIOService.LoadData();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        Close();
    }


    dgTodoList.ItemsSource = _todoDataList;
    _todoDataList.ListChanged += _todoDataList_ListChanged;
}
private void _todoDataList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded || e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted || e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
    {
        try
        {
            _fileIOService.SaveData(sender);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

TodoModel.cs

```
internal class TodoModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isDone;
    private string _text;
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public bool IsDone
    {
        get { return _isDone; }
        set 
        {
            if (_isDone == value)
                return;
            _isDone = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDone");
        }
    }
    public string Text
    { 
        get { return _text; }
        set 
        { 
            if (_text == value)
                return;
            _text = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }
```